# python substrn cells in a column dataframe

Tags: python, find, substr

I have this data frame with this kind of column:

```
hmtl
<div data-wrapper="true" style="font-size:9pt;font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;"><div>DCG_QLKNDFALGKFNDGOIQERKNGLÑADKFNGOWQIREG</div></div>
```

I need to clean this up and leave from "DCG_" up to where `"</div>"` begins:

```
DCG_QLKNDFALGKFNDGOIQERKNGLÑADKFNGOWQIREG
```

Most of the cells in this column vary where the "DCG_" is located as well as the `"</div>"`, I'm trying to use the following code line for this:

```
df['html'] = df['html'].str[df['html'.str.find('DCG_':]
```

but it just returns all null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), where you specify a regular expression and extract anything in any capture groups in the first match:

```
>>> df['extracted'] = df['html'].str.extract("(DCG_.*?)</div>")
>>> df.to_dict()
```

which gives:

```
{'html': {0: '<div data-wrapper="true" style="font-size:9pt;font-family:\'Segoe UI\',\'Helvetica Neue\',sans-serif;"><div>DCG_QLKNDFALGKFNDGOIQERKNGLÑADKFNGOWQIREG</div></div>'},
 'extracted': {0: 'DCG_QLKNDFALGKFNDGOIQERKNGLÑADKFNGOWQIREG'}}
```

---

Regex explanation [Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/oLXBLR/1):

```
(DCG_.*?)</div>
(       )        : Capturing group
 DCG_            : Literally DCG_
     .*?         : Zero or more of any character, lazy match
         </div>  : Literally </div>
```